# Unable to retrieve value from tkinter Listbox after closing the main window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, listbox, window

I have designed a Tkinter listbox which looks like this:

[image: Tkinter Listbox]

When I am in the main loop I can select the options 'A', 'B', etc and print it in the console. When I click proceed the window closes. Below is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

main = Tk()
main.title("Parameter Selection")
main.geometry("800x300")
main.configure(bg='mint cream')
frame = ttk.Frame(main, padding=(3, 3, 12, 12))
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))
scrollbar = Scrollbar(main)

person = StringVar()
person.set("A B C D E")

lstbox1 = Listbox(frame, listvariable=person, selectmode=MULTIPLE, width=15, height=8)
lstbox1.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=2)
lstbox1.configure(background="skyblue4", foreground="white", font=('Aerial 13'))

def select1():
    reslist = list()
    seleccion = lstbox1.curselection()
    for i in seleccion:
        entry = lstbox1.get(i)
        reslist.append(entry)
    for val in reslist:
        print(val)
    return reslist

def quit():
    main.destroy()

btn1 = ttk.Button(frame, text="Select Person Name", command=select1)
btn1.grid(column=1, row=3)

destroy_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Proceed", command=quit)
destroy_button.grid(column=10, row=13)

main.mainloop()
```

Now I try to retrieve these entry value in another file. Code below:

```
import main

person = main.select1()
print(person)
```

Ideally, in combobox or some other Tkinter framework, I am able to retrieve value like this because `quit()` function in the first code is destroying the window. But in this one I am getting this error from the listbox implementation file:

```
return self._getints(self.tk.call(self._w, 'curselection')) or ()**
  _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!listbox"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't retrieve the `Listbox` values after calling `quit()` because it call `main.destroy()` which deletes all the children attached to the `Tk` instance. To workaround that you could make your <kbd>Select Person Name</kbd> button call a function that saves a copy of the items selected in the `Listbox` into a module level global variable, and then change your `select1()` function return the contents of *that*.

Here's your code with those changes:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

main = Tk()
main.title("Parameter Selection")
main.geometry("800x300")
main.configure(bg='mint cream')
frame = ttk.Frame(main, padding=(3, 3, 12, 12))
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))
scrollbar = Scrollbar(main)

person = StringVar()
person.set("A B C D E")

lstbox1 = Listbox(frame, listvariable=person, selectmode=MULTIPLE, width=15, height=8)
lstbox1.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=2)
lstbox1.configure(background="skyblue4", foreground="white", font=('Aerial 13'))

reslist = list()

def save_selection():
    reslist.clear()
    selections = lstbox1.curselection()
    for i in selections:
        entry = lstbox1.get(i)
        reslist.append(entry)
    for val in reslist:
        print(val)

def select1():
    return reslist

def quit():
    main.destroy()

btn1 = ttk.Button(frame, text="Select Person Name", command=save_selection)
btn1.grid(column=1, row=3)

destroy_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Proceed", command=quit)
destroy_button.grid(column=10, row=13)

main.mainloop()
```